# Why does Python evaluate strings/numbers as True in if statements yet myNumber == True returns False?

Tags: python, string, boolean, evaluation, truthiness

The following will print `'ok'`:

```
if 5:
   print('ok')
```

Yet when I do:

```
print(5 == True)
```

The output is `False`.

The same thing happens with strings. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're testing different things here.

The `if` just checks if the `bool` of the expression (see also ["Truth value testing"](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)) is `True` not if the identity is equal to `True`.

So what is actually tested by the `if` is:

```
>>> bool(5) == True
True
```

Comment: So Python implicitly casts numbers and strings to bools in such cases?

Comment: Well, the `if` (but also `and`, `or`, `while`, etc.) require a "truth value" so it's not really implicit.

Answer (score 0):

True has value 1. If you set `True = 5` (only in python 2) the equality become True. The 'if' statement is like it is checking if the guard is not 0 or None so every number not 0 is ok to enter in the first block. In fact False has value 0.